# Google Chrome 16 issues with ASP.NET forms authentication cookie

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, cookies, ashx

I have a problem with Google Chrome 16 on one of the sites I'm supporting that I can't fix couple a days now.

The site is using forms authentication. There is a hyperlink that when clicked is calling a web handler, that is supposed to go fetch a PDF file. Everything is working great in all browsers except in Google Chrome.

When I click that link in Chrome it gives me `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`. I've checked the request headers and the only difference I can see is that the authentication cookie is not present in the request made by Chrome 16. The strange thing is that everything is working great on the local machine, but once uploaded to the production server chrome is not sending that cookie.

I've implemented IReadOnlySessionState interface in the web handler, as suggested here and there in forums, but this didn't solve the issue.

Does any of you have an idea why chrome is acting like that?

Comment: Check Chrome's security configuration. This happened on another ASP.NET site I know of and it treated the cookie as third party, then blocked it.  Hence, the error.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the input. Could you be a bit more specific? I've tried to find something like IE's "trusted sites" but i couldn't find it. I'm sorry but i'm not that much into Chrome, yet :)

Answer (score 0):

To check your cookie acceptance:

1. Click the wrench icon (Top Right)
2. Click "Options"
3. Click "Under the Hood"
4. Click "Content Settings"
5. Make sure that "Block third-party cookies from being set" isn't
   checked.

That was what fixed the issue on the site I was on.  You can also see a special icon in the address bar on the right when it blocks a cookie.

For more precision there is a "Manage Exceptions" button under cookies in the Content Settings.  You can use that to specifically allow the site in question.

Comment: Third party cookies are allowed, I've allowed the site in Exceptions and still it gives me that error. Thanks for your time and effort :-)